# How does a Parent variable store a Child that is larger than Parent?

Tags: java, memory, methods, overriding

I am a beginner in java right now and confused in certain concepts.

Suppose there is a parent class and a child class. Methods are overridden between 
the two.
If I do this:

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

How exactly is memory allocated for the object?
Supposing memory of parent is 32 bytes and child class has 2 bytes extra making it 34 bytes.

So how exactly a 32 byte `Parent` holds 34 byte `Child`?

Comment: That's something you... really should not be asking yourself. Just assume Java knows how to handle it's memory for now. But if you really want to know: a new instance of type `Child` will be created (with whatever bytesize it has) and `Parent p` will point towards the memory location of this object.

Comment: Everything in Java is a reference value so `Parent p` is just pointing to a memory location without having a size of it's own (well other than the size of the pointer)

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with method overriding?

Comment: @JornVernee I am assuming they think that something changes in memory when you override the methods of a superclass vs. not overriding them. Kind off the reason why I suggested to not care too much about that when being new to Java. It's not really something one should be concerned about right off the bat.

Comment: To give an answer wrt. overriding... there are three memory areas in Java: Heap, Stack and Method area. Methods of classes (be they static or not) are stored solely in the Method area. Java keeps record of which methods of which classes are stored where. When you call some method on an object, at run time the (dynamic) type is determined and the corresponding method is called. Thus, you have a separation between the objects and their methods.

Comment: @Ben,thnx for the answer,took a bit of more net surfing, but understood what u meant

Comment: thnx @Turing85 for the extra info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get this question, you need to understand how data is stored in the memory.

when you declare a variable of a primitive data type, the memory will allocate a storage space for that data. If you assign a value for that variable, the value will be stored in that space.
[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUWG0.png)

The thing is different with object. When you declare an object variable of class B,
for example:
"B obj_var;"
the memory will allocate a space memory to save an address to an object that has the B's class properties (either the same class, or a class that extends A). If you just declare the variable, it will contain a value of null.

When you create an object, for example: "new B()"
the object will be created in the memory and will be given an address. In this case, you don't save the address, so you can't access the object or reuse it.

If you write "B obj_var = new B();", you do 3 things at once:
1- create an object variable on the LEFT HAND SIDE.
2- create an object on the RIGHT HAND SIDE.
3- assign the object's address to the object variable, so the object's address is 
   saved in the object variable.
 [see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMyl9.png)
you visit the link below to learn more about how the data is stored in memory: 
https://www.guru99.com/java-stack-heap.html

so the answer to your question is that when you type "Parent p", the memory will allocate a space to an address, so its size will relates to how many bytes the computer need to represent an address, not the class.
When you type "new Child()", an object of the child class will be created at its own size.
Since the Child class is a child of the Parent class, we can refer to the Child class by an object variable of the Parent class "Parent p = new Child();".

It's not an object stored inside its parent, it's an object's address stored on its object variable.